# Celery worker go out of memory while running

Tags: celery

I'm new in celery and I try to integrate celery with fast-api and rabitmq as broker the problem is when i start a worker with the command

```
 celery -A celery_worker.celery worker --loglevel=info
```

I go out of memory it's take more than 5 GB of RAM the project contain a lot of script with some heavy deep learning model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case anyone have the same problem try to add the pool parameter

```
celery -A celery_worker.celery worker --loglevel=info --pool gevent
```